# How to use callback ref using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to use callback ref to position the dialog in the center of the button using react.

i am calculating the dailog poistion based on the button. however the position calculation is done before the button is rendered.

so i am trying to use callback ref such that there is a rerender.

below is my code,

```
function Parent () {
    const iconRef = React.createRef();
    const iconRect = iconRef && iconRef.current && iconRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        <button ref={iconRef}/>
        <Child buttonRect={iconRect}/>
    );
}


function Child({buttonRect}: Props) {
   const getTop = () => {
       const rect = buttonRect;
       return (rect ? rect.bottom : 0) + 24;
   };

   const getLeft = () => {
       const dialogRect = getRect(dialogRef.current);
       if (!buttonRect || !dialogRect) return 0;
       const middleOfButton = buttonRect.left + buttonRect.width / 2;

       return middleOfButton - dialogRect.width / 2;
   };
   const dialogRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
   return (
       {buttonRect ? 
           <div class="wrapper">
               <div class="dialog" ref ={dialogRef} 
                   style={{
                       top: getTop() + 'px',
                       left: getLeft() + 'px',
                   }}>
               </div>
           </div>
        }
    );
}
```

Now the problem is i am rendering the dialog only when the buttonrect has some value. but still the dialog left is not calculated prooperly unless forceUpdate used in Useeffect in child component.

i dont want to use forceUpdate. i want to use  get the rect in parent component using a callback ref. With a callback ref i want to set the buttonrect to state, thus guaranteeing an update.

how can i do this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Pass in a function inside of a ref? It’s likely ref.current will be undefined when child is rendered.

Comment: i am not sure how to use callback ref in the first place. new to using react. i am trying to somehow update the position of this dialog such that it is aligned with tthe center of button and some space added to dailog (got by getLeft) whatever the width of dialog may be. (dynamic content)

Comment: @evolutionxbox: or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: There probably is, but I don’t know it yet.

Comment: okay. but do you know how to set the the iconRef of parent component to state using callback ref? since i am new to using react refs not knowing how to do it

Comment: Not sure. AFAIK ref isn’t state, so it can’t cause re-renders.

Comment: but is there a way to store that iconRef rect into state and pass it to child and that in turn causes update?

Comment: Why not try it? I’m not convinced that putting a ref in state will do much. Being proven wrong here would be good.

Comment: i dont know how to do it. just that i am getting ideas :)